# How to obtain all rows in MySQL table where a column's value is the same?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a SQL novice here. Suppose we have the following table:

```
id              type
1               A   
2               A
3               B
4               B
5               C
6               C
7               D
8               D
...
```

Let's say that I do not know the possible values under the column '**type**' and assume that it can be one of N number of possible values. In MySQL, how can I form a query to obtain all rows for a single **type** (either *randomly* select one type or take the first alphabetically sorted type)?

Desired output:

```
id              type
1               A   
2               A
```

or

```
id              type
5               C   
6               C
```

or

```
id              type
7               D   
8               D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose a random type and get all the rows using:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = (select t2.type from t t2 order by rand() limit 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `RANK()` here, for a MySQL 8+ solution:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY type) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, type
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

This approach would return all records for the alphabetically lowest `type` value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get first `type` sorted alphabatically then use `min`(or use `max` for last type) as follows:

```
select t.*
  from your_table t
 where t.type = (select min(tt.type) from your_table tt);
```